# Display Bootstrap 3 Dropdown Sub Menu Without Click

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I found how to create bootstrap dropdown sub menu on http://bootply.com/92442, but I want to show the sub menu without click it. I've removed comment on this code:

```
/*.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu{display:block;}*/
```

and it's still not working. How to activate bootstrap dropdown menu on hover?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add data-hover="dropdown" where you'd put data-toggle="dropdown"

http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/CWSpear/bootstrap-hover-dropdown/blob/master/demo.html

Comment: this plugins gives you the above feature http://cameronspear.com/demos/bootstrap-hover-dropdown/

Comment: there you don't need a plugin. the problem with this is, that bootstrap not support submenus. if you have, it would be collapse all

Comment: its same plugin as Narayana gave